# Replacing word in different ways

Tags: c#, .net, string

For first I have phrase like `ice z comp`. In the output I need `List<string>` which have this word with dashes for example like this: `ice-z comp, ice z-comp, ice-z-comp`

For now I have this:

```
var synonymFromSynonym = new List<string>();
var countOfSpaces = word.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace);
for (int x = 0; x < countOfSpaces; x++)
{
    // What here for my output ?
}
```

Comment: Here is an algorithm: (1) Find the position of all the spaces in the string; (2) Loop through all numbers from 0 up to `2^n`, with `n` the number of spaces; (3) Consider each such number as a set of flags of which the `i`th bit indicates whether to replace the `i`th space by a dash or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using the following implementation. First, the input is split into the individual words.

```
var Words = word.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
```

Then, the words are assembled again, considering two cases, namely whether the connection is done with a space or with a hyphen. This can be done recursively as follows, where a call like `GenerateResult("", 0 )` would start the calculation.

```
List<string> Result = new List<string>();

void GenerateResult(string Intermediate, int Position)
{
    if (Position == Words.Count() - 1) // base case, nothing to append
    {
        Result.Add(Intermadiate);
    }
    else
    {
        GenerateResult( Intermediate + " ", Position + 1 ); // space case
        GenerateResult( Intermediate + "-", Position + 1 ); // hyphen case
    }
}
```